# autopilot deploy fails at 99% - Configure availability zones

Tags: juju, maas, openstack

I'm having a difficult time with the autopilot deployment of openstack. I have set up a lab where I have a MAAS server with two network interfaces: one that is on my office private network of `10.x.x.x` and the other interface I have a `172.16.0.1`. This second interface does the DHCP and DNS.

I have followed the instructions for autopilot deployment but it fails at the configure availability zones with this as the details:

```
Missing nova-compute units: [u'xxxxx', u'xxxxx', u'xxxxx']
```

I saw in the `/var/log/juju/unit-nova-compute-1.log` of all the machines this message but it contained nothing for nova-compute service:

```
INFO juju-log Found subordinate_configuration on nova-ceilometer:38
```

Greatly appreciate any help. Thanks.